# Is there a way to format and sort dates in a drop-down list on Google Sheets?

Tags: date, drop-down-menu, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have made a monthly budget sheet for someone who is not too confident using Google Sheets (or Excel) so I need it to be really simple.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10E9jX1Qlq-KQLCHupci3_8MiP7p5l-f2J1M5yFtfjQ0/edit?usp=sharing

In the monthly report, it is possible to select a month in cell B1 to fetch the relevant amounts using `sumproduct`/`hlookup` formulas.

Now that person should write "April 2019" or "May 2019" etc.

I would like to insert a dropdown list so there is no format issue whatsoever and for the items to be shown this way:

```
April 2019
May 2019
June 2019
...
```

with something like 24 months available.

I made a dropdown list from a formatted cell range but the dates display as "01-04-2019, 01-05-2019, etc" so it is not visually easy without an "mmmm aaa" format
AND 
are not sorted chronologically (although my cell range is, but they rearrange themselves after 1 selection)

Going further, the dropdown would ideally have:

- months in the format "mmmm yyyy"
- sorted chronologically
- dynamic list (12 months history, no future months)

Comment: `mmmm aaa` = `April Sat.` are you sure you want that?

Comment: sorry you're right it is mmmm yyy I'll edit the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will give you dynamic dates in the range of **(today's month +1) 2018** until **(today's month +1) 2019**

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(TEXT(TO_DATE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("A"&EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY())-1, MONTH(TODAY())+1, 1), -1)+1):
 INDIRECT("A"&EOMONTH(DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY())+1, 1), 0)))), 
 "mmmm yyyy")))
```

[image: 0]
[image]

Comment: Hi player0, I have actually tried to do the same for full years but I couldn't make it
I would like to make a simple list like this one:
2017
2018
2019
so years n-2, n-1 and n. Do you have a solution for this?
thanks a lot in advance! Greg

Comment: thank you for your message! this displays the list I want but I cannot use it as a date in my filters (see https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10E9jX1Qlq-KQLCHupci3_8MiP7p5l-f2J1M5yFtfjQ0/edit?usp=sharing : 
Categories! A16:A18 is what I use but is ugly in filter yearly!B1
-----------  Categories! B16 is what I had made out of your first formula but is not stored as a date and doesn't work as a filter (counts 2017-2019 days = year 1905)

Comment: I fixed your formulae: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10E9jX1Qlq-KQLCHupci3_8MiP7p5l-f2J1M5yFtfjQ0/edit#gid=1476866686

Comment: Hi, thank you, it does work! however when I paste the formula into my actual sheet it still returns an error :(
Actually I never understood the first formula, the use of row and indirect I don't understand. Would you mind telling me a little about it? (most important would be to tell me what else you did besides the formula so I can replicate the success in the other sheet?
Sorry for being so thick :l

Comment: perhaps try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(ROW(INDIRECT("A"&YEAR(TODAY())-2&":A"&YEAR(TODAY()))))`

Comment: I'm sorry it still doesn't work. I created a copy of the workbook, if you have time to take a look! https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gY6DIHW55OvjZEOra6dPVu0UXgAFm6ytYk0EFeNAKtY/edit#gid=1476866686
Thank you very much

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: sorry about that: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gY6DIHW55OvjZEOra6dPVu0UXgAFm6ytYk0EFeNAKtY/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iNpTb_lv1yxx4N4H5ERzycMGug9ky5G_yVTt83h13iY/edit#gid=1476866686

Comment: This is making me feel so stupid. It works in your sheet however in mine it just writes "2019" (...) that becomes converted to 1905 when formatted as a date. 
Did you do anything apart from writing the formula? something in data validation or in cell format? (your sheet is protected so i cannot see)

Comment: Also, the first formula (used for months list) with format changed to "yyyy" instead of "mmmm aaaa" does not get converted to a number however it still doesn't work with the dropdown list.

Comment: as I already said I fixed your formulas in yearly sheet. I removed "year" from before each C1 reference. so for example in C4 you had `=SUMPRODUCT(year(budget!1:1)=year($C$1),budget!11:11)-C11` but it should be `=SUMPRODUCT(year(budget!1:1)=($C$1),budget!11:11)-C11`

Comment: I'll be damned. Understood. I completely missed the plural... Thanks a million. I did not think to check these formulas at all.